# Web archive links without header

Tags: links, archive.org

Is it possible to link to an archived web page from the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine so that the archive header (for browsing other archives of the same page) isn't shown? Perhaps an url parameter? I didn't find anything on their [FAQ](http://archive.org/about/faqs.php).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

from "*Wikipedia Help:Using the Wayback Machine*" : <sub>(**[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Using_the_Wayback_Machine#Specific_archive_copy)**)</sub>

> ### Specific archive copy
>
> Once the target web page has been archived, each of the specific dated archives can be individually requested using the format shown below.
> The next example links to the archived copy of the main index page of Wikipedia exactly as it appeared on `30 September 2002 at 12:35:25 pm` in the [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC) timezone.
> The datetime format is **`YYYYMMDDhhmmss`**.
> <sub>(examples are archives of this question.)</sub>
>
> - [`https://web.archive.org/web/20020930123525/http://www.wikipedia.org/`](https://web.archive.org/web/20020930123525/http://www.wikipedia.org/)
>
> Use the above format to link directly to a specific archive copy.
>
> Adding an **asterisk** (`*`) immediately after the date (or in place of it) is a quick way to show the calendar view of all archived copies.
>
> The following flags can be appended to the datetime field to modify the format in which the archived content is displayed:
>
> - **`id_`** Identity - the **original** resource, return it as it was archived. <sub><sup>[example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813181552id_/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40911/web-archive-links-without-header)</sup></sub>
> - **`js_`** JavaScript - return document marked up as **JavaScript**. <sub><sup>[example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813181552js_/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40911/web-archive-links-without-header)</sup></sub>
> - **`cs_`** CSS - return document marked up as **CSS**.  <sub><sup>[example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813181552cs_/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40911/web-archive-links-without-header)</sup></sub>
> - **`im_`** Image - return document **as an image**.  <sub><sup>[example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813181552im_/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40911/web-archive-links-without-header)</sup></sub>
> - **`if_`** iFrame - normal archive except **without the navigational toolbar**.  <sub><sup>[example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813181552if_/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40911/web-archive-links-without-header)</sup></sub>
>
> Depending on the circumstances under which the page images were archived, the rendering of these pages may not be consistent... The datetime format is `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`, followed by an optional formatting flag, such as the ones above.

Comment: This is really great! I'm marking it as the accepted answer because it is more comprehensive and explains the meaning behind the various suffixes (which might finally allow me to memorize them and stop having to refer back to this question! )

Comment: Do all of these still work? A lot of them seem to be just loading the page without any CSS. The best option for what the question asked seems to be **`if_`**.

Answer (score 16):

Append `id_` to the end of the date string in the url.

- http://web.archive.org/web/19981111184551/http://google.com/ (Header shown)
- http://web.archive.org/web/19981111184551id_/http://google.com/ (No header)

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20130329115724/http://faq.web.archive.org/page-without-wayback-code/

> If you want to view a page from the Wayback Machine that does not have
> all of the Wayback rewritten code in it, you can view the bare,
> archived page by adding “id_” to the end of the date in the URL.
>
> Page with rewritten links and other Wayback code in it:
>
> - http://web.archive.org/web/20051001001126/http://www.archive.org/
>
> Page rendered exactly as it was archived:
>
> - http://web.archive.org/web/20051001001126id_/http://www.archive.org/

Comment: That's amazing, thanks! I was afraid it wouldn't be possible :)

Comment: Thanks for this method, but this also keeps the original hyperlinks intact, so absolute links or links relative to the server root (begining with a slash "/") will not work (or they will not point to archived pages). Is there a way to just get rid of the header, but make the links work?

Comment: try "im_" instead if "id_". with the latter some websites also lose the CSS so i wold deprecate the use of id as it almost useless

Comment: Thanks for posting this phwd: Happy to report that this (suffixing either `id_` or `im_`) still works. Checked 2017-Dec-17. Also thanks to @Francesco for your contribution.

Comment: When you have to use the Wayback Machine to get that [FAQ page](http://web.archive.org/web/20131010215627/http://faq.web.archive.org/page-without-wayback-code/) 

Comment: im_ and id_ don't seem to make a difference concerning css, it's always broken. Except for the with-header version.

Comment: Suffixing `if_` works and preserves styles

Answer (score 3):

As commenter *fzbd* states, appending `if_` (not `id_`) to the date string works best.

- http://web.archive.org/web/20200101000208/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

  - Header shown
- http://web.archive.org/web/20200101000208if_/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

  - No header shown

The problem with `id_` is that you lose a lot of resources you most likely want. It is less apparent in *phwd*'s answer because google.com is used as the example, and that page includes almost everything in that single page's source and not as external resources. For the vast majority of websites, `id_` will cause serious breakage. For example, using again this website:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20200101000208id_/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

  - Quite broken albeit no header shown